# how to use <!--nextpage--> in custom single.php template using php?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-query, pagination

I know how to use `<!--nextpage-->` to break the page in to multiple pages from wordpress admin area. But i want to use that page break using theme single.php file.

I'm using custom fields to design my single post template and after few fields i want to put `<!--nextpage-->` to break the page. But the post is ignoring the page break and showing all the content in single page only. How can we integrate put the `<!--nextpage-->` in theme programatically?

here is my single post template

```
<?php
get_header();
echo the_title();

echo get_field('moviename');
echo get_field('moviedescription');
?>

<!--nextpage-->

<?php
echo get_field('movienews');
echo get_field('moviegallery');
?>

<!--nextpage-->

<?php
echo get_field('movieinfo');
echo get_field('moviesongs');
?>

<!--nextpage-->

<?php
echo the_content();

get_footer();
?>
```

in the above code, `<--nextpage-->` is not working as it should.

Comment: Can you update your question with the contents of your `single.php`?

Comment: Updated, please have a look once.

Comment: Ahh I see - yes, `<!-- nextpage -->` only works _in the post content editor_ - you can't just stick them in your template and expect it to work!